# How to hand over several parameters with post/get to a server in c#, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to transfer 2 parameters to the server, one is an IFormCollection, the other one is a "normal" object.
I tried do put both parameters in a model and transfer this model as the "only" parameter, but this doesnt work.

- When I only transfer the IFormCollection, the following endpoint-signature in the controller works:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("the route")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Guid projectId, IFormCollection formCollection)
```

- And when I only transfer the object in the body, the following endpoint-signature in the controller works:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("the route")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Guid projectId, [FromBody] MyObject object)
```

As mentioned above, I put both parameters in a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public IFormCollection FormCollection { get; set; }
  public CaeObject Template { get; set; }
}
```

But now, none of the endpoint signatures work:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Guid projectId, [FromBody] MyModel model)
  public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(Guid projectId, MyModel model)
```

The endpoint-code is not entered, somewhere earlier an --> **400 (Bad Request)** <-- error occurs.

How can i combine two parameters in a model, where one parameter is transferred in the body and the other one is not?
Or how to transfer the two parameters without combining in a model?

Thx

Comment: You have to show  get and post views  and actions to see how you create and use these objects

Comment: Check http response, it’s probably has error details, which fields in request are not valid. Use Postman or Fiddler Composer to play with request structure until your request will match your model

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found:

On the client, besides the file I also add my object to the FormData:

```
formData.append('template', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

On the server, I fetch my object (the JSONObject) and create myObject with:

```
formCollection.TryGetValue("template", out var myObjectAsJson);
MyObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(myObjectAsJson.ToString());
```

So I still transfer only *one* parameter to the server.